# How to get window scroll bar position using Cypress

Tags: cypress

I use `Cypress` for functional testing. And want to test or window vertical scrollbar has specific positions.

I tried:

```
    cy.document().then((doc) => {                                                                                           
      cy.window().then(win => {                                                                                             
        const doc = document.documentElement;                                                                                 
        const left = (window.pageXOffset || doc.scrollLeft) - (doc.clientLeft || 0);                                          
        const top = (window.pageYOffset || doc.scrollTop)  - (doc.clientTop || 0);                                            

        console.log(top, left)  // 0, 0                                                                                            
      })                                                                                                                    
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

you can scroll the window using the scrollTo method

```
cy.window().scrollTo('bottom')
// ---- or
cy.window().scrollTo(0, 100)
```

the full api is here 
[enter link description here](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/scrollto.html#Syntax)

If you want to test the value of the position of a scroll you can use the scrollTop for the vertical scroll

```
cy.window().invoke('scrollTop').should('eq', 100)
```